# a regular expression for substring or exact match

Tags: java, regex, string

Given the example string "hello", I need an expression for validating user input (any combination of the existing letters; without repeating a used letter).

In this context valid and invalid input examples are as follows:

valid: "hello", "hell", "lol" .... etc.

invalid: "heel", "loo"... etc.

I have tried the likes of ...

```
(.)*([hello])(.)*
```

and

```
[hello]+
```

But, they don't sort the invalid ones.

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

**NOTE:** This is not just substring or exact match, per the examples, combinations of letters are valid.

Comment: why is `lol` a valid entry?

Comment: well i want the user to be able to create any word from a given combination of letters

Comment: Explain the variations in Valid and Invalid answers and strengthen the language to provide a complete question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions is not the right tool...they should be used for matching left to right, not counting various characters in a random order. You're better off having a validation string `hello`, looping through each character from the input string, and checking to see if the character exists (if it does, remove that character from the validation string and continue. otherwise, the input fails).

Here is a [quick example I whipped up in Java](http://ideone.com/eTAhGM):

```
public static boolean testString(String testString)
{
    String allowedCharacters = "hello";

    for(int i = 0; i < testString.length(); i++) {
        int position = allowedCharacters.indexOf(testString.charAt(i));

        if(position == -1) {
            System.out.println(testString + " - fail");
            return false;
        } else {
            allowedCharacters = allowedCharacters.substring(0, position)
                              + allowedCharacters.substring(position + 1);
        }
    }


    System.out.println(testString + " - success");
    return true;
}
```

Calling the function with example output:

```
testString("hello"); // hello - success
testString("hell");  // hell - success
testString("lol");   // lol - success

testString("heel");  // heel - fail
testString("loo");   // loo - fail
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sam, I was hoping there might be a short little expression is all. I have a solution very similar yours as is so I think I'll just leave it as is. Thanks again for your input

Comment: This may be possible with an expression, but it would not be short. And could become wildly inefficient as well as confusing for developers to read/edit. I'd stick with the reusable function you are using :)

Comment: Thanks Sam, will do :)